# Node.js fetch SWAPI results returns memory error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, async-await, out-of-memory

I'm trying to understand async features of the Node.js. I'm trying to fetch data from a dummy data source (in this case [SWAPI](https://swapi.co/)) and return the results when there is a request.

My function inside the router is;

```
const url = "https://swapi.co/api/people/?page="
    const getData = async (url, page) => {
        let n = []
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(url + page);
            const data = response.data;
            for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                n.push(data.results[i].name)
            }
            return n;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    const getAllData = async () => {
        const firstPage = await getData(url, 1);
        const secondPage = await getData(url, 2);
        let allPages = firstPage.concat(secondPage);
        for (var i = 0; iDisplayStart< i < iDisplayLength; i++) {
            aaData.push([
                iDisplayStart + i,
                iDisplayStart + i,
                allPages[i]
            ]);
        }
        var ret = {
            sEcho: "",
            iTotalRecords: 600000,
            iTotalDisplayRecords: aaData.length,
            aaData: aaData
        };
        return res.json(ret);
    }
    getAllData()
```

But when I make a call to this endpoint, the computer freezes. So I started watching the memory state from the top menu and ran the Node backend server from the terminal. Now it is returning the error below and I don't know how to overcome this problem.

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

```
1: node::Abort() [node]   
2: 0x55d4acb8a011 [node]   
3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]   
4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]  
5: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [node]   
6: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node] 
7: 0x2a52e9040bd Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I'm trying to run your code in Node, but I get `iDisplayStart is not defined`, `iDisplayLength is not defined`, `aaData is not defined`, etc. I stopped here

Comment: Yes, there are some variables not declared in the above snippet, That's why I make a normalize code below, First check for output data. If data comes then perform such operation like `sorting` and `filtering` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Let's put this code and then perform some loops.

```
const getData = async (url, page) => {
  try {
    const nums = [];
    const response = await axios.get(url + page);
    const { data } = response;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i += 1) {
      const obj = data.results[i];
      nums.push(obj.name);
    }
    return nums;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
};

const getAllData = async () => {
  const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=';
  const firstPage = await getData(url, 1);
  const secondPage = await getData(url, 2);
  const allPages = firstPage.concat(secondPage);
  console.log(allPages);
  return allPages;
};

const result = getAllData();
console.log(result);
```